# How can you get the selected rows from a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

So I've written this code to put a checkmark beside a row that I want selected because I want multiple selected rows

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:path];

if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
```

but when I use the method:

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [self.LightsView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

it only gets the last row that I clicked on.  Is the checkmark not selecting it?

Comment: Nope, selected is the row that was tapped last and was not unselected yet. Nothing to do with cells' accessories. You need to keep track of "selected" (let's call them checked, that would be more appropriate) rows yourself.

Comment: Also make sure that your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` recognizes that cells can be reused, and as such, it will have to reset the `accessoryType` for the row as appropriate; don't try to rely on the `accessoryType` to know whether you "checked" a row or not. Have a separate model backing your tableview keeping track of which rows were "checked" and have your above code update that model as well as the UI, and have `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` refer to that model, too.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For the `indexPathsForSelectedRows:` method to work properly, you have to configure the table view to allow multiple selection of cells:

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;
```