# How to Set a tag Value in UITAbleView Cell and Pass It into URL in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tags

i am Newbie in iOS Development, i make an App that Contain `UITableView` I want to Set a Tag to `UITableViewCell` like as if it Was Selected then Cell tag is `1` else cell tag is `0` for that i Do Coding like as But it was always Set tag is equal `1` i want if cell was selected then tag is `1` else tag is equal to `0` Please Give me Solution for it.

Here my Code like as

in `viewDidLoad`

```
NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
SelectedRows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[userDef objectForKey:@"SelectedRows"]];
```

SelectedRows is `NSMutableArray`

```
-(CategoryCustumCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
CategoryCustumCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CategoryCustumCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
cell.categoryLabel.text=[self.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.tag=1;
    intValue=cell.tag;
    NSLog(@"Tag %d",intValue);
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    cell.tag=0;
    NSLog(@"Tag %d",cell.tag);
}
return cell;
}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
CategoryCustumCell *cell = (CategoryCustumCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *selectedCell= cell.categoryLabel.text;
NSLog(@"Selected Cell Value %@",selectedCell);

NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    [SelectedRows removeObject:obj];
    [tableView reloadData];
}else{
    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    [SelectedRows addObject:obj];
    [tableView reloadData];
}

NSUserDefaults *userDef = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDef setObject:SelectedRows forKey:@"SelectedRows"];
[userDef synchronize];
}
```

And i Pass this Tag Value in Url Like as

```
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/insert_gcm.php?gcm_id=%@& category1=%d&category2=%d&category3=%d&category4=%d&category5 =%d&category6=%d&category7 =%d&category8=%d& category9=%d",uniqueIdentifier,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue]];
```

Here i want tag Value `1` if cell was Selected and tag Value `0` if cell is not selected Please Give me Solution for it

Comment: Why are you using `indexPath.section` ? Use `indexPath.row` need a lot of changes in the current implementation.

Comment: @MidhunMP Here my Tableview Contain Section So i wrote index path.Section. it is Not Matter For me `indexpath.section` or `index path.row` i want only tag Value.

Comment: How many rows you have in a section ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Only One Row for each Section.

Comment: Where are you putting this NSURL *url=... line and how are you calculating intValue?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i Put Url On my `Save Button` Click and i set intValue as int and it's Default Value is `0`.

Comment: What do you mean "i set intValue as int"? How are you going about getting that int?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i mean i set intValue is `@interface TableViewController ()
{
    int intValue;
}` and i set Default Value is like as `0`.

Comment: I see the general problem, but are the save buttons part of your cells? Or is there only one save button? And if so, how do you want to determine if the tag's 0 or 1?

Comment: @LyndseyScott i have no idea about that so i asked Question Here. Please give me Solution for that.

Comment: I can't answer that because it solely depends on the way your program is structured...

Comment: @LyndseyScott then any Other Solution For TableView Cell Selection State and Set Tag to selected Cell `1` and not selected to `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting `intValue` to 1 in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    cell.tag=1;
    intValue=cell.tag;
    NSLog(@"Tag %d",intValue);
}
```

That's why `intValue` always equals 1.

And the solution is NOT to set the intValue equal to 0 in the other conditional of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Although you're correctly setting your selected cells' tags to 1 and your unselected cells' tags to 0 as you intended, you shouldn't assign your `intValue` variable in this method. Instead, you should set your `intValue` depending on the current tag. For example, if there's a save button in each row, you'll want to set that button's tag to 0 or 1 then utilize the parameter in the the button press method to set `intValue` equal to `sender.tag`.

**Edit:** As was made clear in the comments "intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValue,intValu‌​e" used in forming the url are actually supposed to be different numbers, each one representing a different cell's tag. But by using `intValue` repeatedly like that, you're actually using the same exact value 9 times. You actually need to use 9 different values to do what you're attempting to do.

You can create an array of those 9 values dynamically in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

In `viewDidLoad` you can initialize a class `NSMutableArray` variable with exactly 9 indexes all containing 0:

```
self.tagArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0 ; i < 9 ; i ++) {
    [self.tagArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}
```

Then update those indices in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`:

```
-(CategoryCustumCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // ...

    NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
    if ([SelectedRows containsObject:obj])
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        cell.tag=1;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        cell.tag=0;
    }

    [self.tagArray replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:cell.tag]];
    return cell;
}
```

Then during perform save, use the tags stored in your tag array:

```
- (void)performSave {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.janvajevu.com/webservice/insert_gcm.php?gcm_id=%@&category1=%@&category2=%@&category3=%@&category4=%@&category5=%@&category6=%@&category7=%@&category8=%@&category9=%@", uniqueIdentifier, self.tagArray[0], self.tagArray[1], self.tagArray[2], self.tagArray[3], self.tagArray[4], self.tagArray[5], self.tagArray[6], self.tagArray[7], self.tagArray[8]]];    
}
```

Comment: i got it but When i select all cell then it set tag `1` only for Seven Cell because my Screen only Contain 7 cell and want to show 8th and 9th cell tableview want to scroll.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper But if you never scroll to cells 8 and 9 they can never be selected... If you scroll to them and select them, then scroll back up, the number 1 should be stored for those rows.

Comment: Scot Here i want my `cell.accessoryType` CheckMark by Default of that i write in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath ` method i write as `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` but it is not work for me please give me solution.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Which part specifically isn't working for you? If you want your cells to be checkmarked by default, you have to store the section number in your SelectedRows array before reloading your table... Have you done that?

Comment: here my All part are working fine but i want as when Tableview open then all cell are Selected and When User unselect it then it was also unselected.

Comment: i do that then tableview Cell is not unselected.

Comment: Here my Question is That when User Launch Application at First time then i want to Show all Table Cell is Check marked and When It is Select then it was Unchecked and When it was Checked again then it was Again Check but in my app at the app Launching all cell are not Check marked it was Uncheked.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper If I understand what you're saying, then like I said earlier: "If you want your cells to be checkmarked by default, you have to store the section number in your SelectedRows array before reloading your table."

Comment: i understand that and i write `[SelectedRows addObject:obj];` in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method then tableview Cell was Selected but when i Select any Cell then it was not Show as Unselected it is remanning as Selected.

Comment: @iOSDeveloper No, you'd add *all* the indexes to SelectedRows in viewDidLoad then call [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: but when i write `NSNumber *obj = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:indexPath.section];
    [SelectedRows addObject:obj];` in ViewDid load then it gives error in index path.section.

Comment: Please Give me Solution for  `add all the indexes to SelectedRows in viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 2):

You are improperly assuming that the cells on which you maintain state will remain associated with the row in question (that is, the cell for row 1 will remain the cell for row 1). This is flatly unreliable because cells get reused based on criteria the system determines.

You'll either need maintain the state you wish in some other data structure or more likely take advantage of the fact that the tableView knows its selection state and you have no need to reinvent that particular wheel: [How can you get the selected rows from a UITableView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886493/how-can-you-get-the-selected-rows-from-a-uitableview)

Whenever you need to build a URL out of the collection of selected rows, ask the tableView, translate the indexPaths into whatever bits of info you need, and carry on.